Showing $A \subseteq B$ implies $\sup A \leqslant \sup B$
I am trying to prove the following exercise:
Let $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with $A \subseteq B$. Further, suppose $A \neq \emptyset$ and $B$ to be bounded above. Show that $\sup  A \leq \sup  B$.
Attempt:
Intuitively, the result seems obvious but I am not sure on how to write it down correctly.
First, there are the "technical conditions", so that the supremum of those sets really exist:
Because $A$ is non-empty, so is $B$. And since $B$ is bounded above and $A \subseteq B$, so is $A$. In conclusion, $\sup  A$ and $\sup  B$ do exist.
Since $A \subseteq B$, we know that for every $a \in A$, there exists $b \in B$ such that $a \leq b$. Further, since the least upper bound of $B$ is a upper bound, we have that for all $b \in B: b \leq \sup B$. Thus, we get: $\forall a \in A: a\leq \sup  B$.
Thus, $\sup A \leq \sup B$, since $\sup A$ is the least upper bound, and we just showed that $\sup B$ a upper bound.
My problem with my current attempt is the following line:

Since $A \subseteq B$, we know that for every $a \in A$ there exists
$b \in B$ such that $a \leq b$.

I am unsure if this is an assumption I am able to make.
Sure, if I think of $A$ and $B$ as intervals then this seems reasonable. My problem is that if $A,B$ are the elements of a sequence, maybe this could be a problematic assumption.
Consider a (bounded) sequence $s_n$ and some some fixed $m \in \mathbb{N}$, then define $B:=\{s_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $A:=\{s_n :n>m \}$. What if $s_n$ is a convergent sequence. In that case, I don't think it would be possible to find a $b \in B$ such that for all $a$ in $A$: $a \leq b$.
Any help would be appreciated.

It suffices to take b = a? The proof can easily be simplified to: "Take $a\in A$. Since $a\in B$ (because $A\subseteq B$), by definition $a\leq \sup(B)$."

The relation of subsets does not translate into an order relation between its elements. $A\subseteq B$ means $a\in A\implies a\in B$.

In your last paragraph your seem to have got your quantifiers confused. We want $\forall a\in A \exists b\in B (a\le b)$. You seem to be puzzled by the fact that perhaps we can't achieve $\exists b\in B\forall a\in A (a\le b)$. But that's not what we need.

If, for a given set $A$, you define $\sup A=\sup{a;a\in A}$, then it is clear that
\begin{equation}
\sup A=\sup{a;a\in A}\leq\sup{a;a\in A\cup B}=\sup B
\end{equation}
granted $A\subset B$ and $\sup B$ exists (which you assumed).

This is of course a duplicate and should be closed as such.

Thank you all very much for your help!

First, I will expand on rafilou2003's comment regarding the proof and later comment on your attempt.
Let $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with $A \subseteq B$. Further suppose $A \neq \emptyset$ and $B$ to be bounded above. Show that $\sup  A \leq \sup  B$.
For a set $S$ ($\subseteq \mathbb{R}$) the supremum, $\sup(S)$ is defined as the least upper bound, thus the following conditions hold 
(i) $\sup(S)$ is a upper bound, i.e. $\forall s \in S: s \leq \sup(S)$. 
(ii) $\sup(S)$ is the smallest upper bound, i.e. if $a$ is a upper bound, then $s \leq a$.
By condition (ii), if we are able to show that some $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is a upper bound to $A$, it by definition (of the supremum) follows that $\sup(A)\leq c$.
Now, as mentioned in the comments, since $\sup(B)$ is in particular a upper bound to $B$ and $A \subseteq B$, we get that $\sup(B)$ is a upper bound to $A$. By condition (ii) the result, $\sup(A)\leq \sup(B)$ follows.

Regarding your problem:
There is nothing wrong with the satement:
Statement 1:\

Since $A \subseteq B$, we know that for every $a \in A$ there exists
$b \in B$ such that $a \leq b$.

Because if $A \subseteq B$, take $b=a$ and trivially $a \leq b$.
Statement 2:\

Consider a (bounded) sequence $s_n$ and some some fixed $m \in
> \mathbb{N}$, then define $B:=\{s_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $A:=\{s_n
> :n>m \}$. What if $s_n$ is a convergent sequence. In that case I don't
think it would be possible to find a $b \in B$ such that for all $a$
in $A$: $a \leq b$.

In the second statement, you worry that there may not $\exists b \in B: \forall a \in A: a \leq b$. 
But the statement 1 (which you tried to find a counterexample to was) $\forall a \in A \exists b \in B : a \leq b$.
That are two different statements.
(Thanks to Jair Taylor for pointing this out.)

Please don't answer duplicate questions. Thank you!

@MartinBrandenburg I am sorry. I just wanted to show him that the assumption he was uneasy about was not needed in the proof. My main point was that said assumption was wrong.

@MartinBrandenburg: How is this a duplicate? This question is specifically about solution-verification, and not asking for a proof.

Thank you for this detailed answer!

In fact, you have used $B \ne \varnothing$.  The result could fail if $B = \varnothing$.

@GEdgar We are told that $A\ne\emptyset$ and $A\subseteq B$.

Your Statement 1 is not the same as the sentence given in the proof. You have switched the order of the quantifiers.

@JairTaylor Thank you, I'll edit it.
